# How to use node-addon-api's AsyncContext asynchronously

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon, n-api, node-addon-api

The docs for [`AsyncContext`](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/master/doc/async_context.md#example) have this example (only slightly modified, but still working) that works synchronously:

```
#include "napi.h"

void MakeCallbackWithAsyncContext(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info)
{
  Napi::Function callback = info[0].As<Napi::Function>();
  Napi::Object resource = info.Env().Global().As<Napi::Object>();;    
  Napi::AsyncContext context(info.Env(), "async_context_test", resource);

  callback.MakeCallback(Napi::Object::New(info.Env()),
      std::initializer_list<napi_value>{}, context);
}
```

I'd like to know how to use this asynchronously - here's my latest shot at it:

```
Napi::AsyncContext* _context;
Napi::FunctionReference* _callback;
Napi::Object* _resource;

void CallBack()
{
  _callback->MakeCallback(*_resource, std::initializer_list<napi_value>{}, *_context);
}

void MakeCallbackWithAsyncContext(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info)
{
  Napi::Function cb = info[0].As<Napi::Function>();
  _callback = new Napi::FunctionReference(Napi::Persistent(cb));
  _callback->SuppressDestruct();

  _resource = new Napi::ObjectReference(Napi::Persistent(env.Global()));
  _resource->SuppressDestruct();

  _context = new Napi::AsyncContext(info.Env(), "async_context_test", _resource->Value());

  // run CallBack() in different thread
}
```

The program crashes inside `CallBack()`.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: @IanHunter I just added an answer on how I resolved this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that node-addon-api's `AsyncContext` cannot be used on a different thread.

What you can do is use the [n-api](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/n-api.html). Luckily, node-addon-api is only a thin wrapper around n-api, and both can be mixed and matched.